# Input box showing in multiple lines text box

Tags: php, html, css, input

The Problem is simple,
  The below shown is an input text box. i've set the value of the input box value. When the page is loaded, it is shown in multiple lines. This happens with chrome browser only. any help
[image]

HTML:
    `<input type="text" name="q" id="search_q" value="why is this happening in the input box">`

Here is the css for the input box

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], select {
border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
padding: 3px 5px;
border-radius: 4px;
background: white;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,white), color-stop(0%,white), color-stop(100%,#F2F2F2));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%,white 0%,#F2F2F2 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%,white 0%,#F2F2F2 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%,white 0%,#F2F2F2 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='white', endColorstr='#F2F2F2',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, white 0%,white 0%,#F2F2F2 100%);
}
map.generic.css:155
input, textarea {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial;
color: #333;
font-size: 16px;
}
map.generic.css:148
input, a, div, textarea, img {
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
map.generic.css:142
input, a, div, textarea, img, li {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

another image after font-size reduced:
[image: after font-size:11px]

Comment: When you select that box and write something yourself that is longer than the width, does it overflow to another line?

Comment: Are there anymore styles being applied this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8d3R/1/) looks fine in Chrome. How does it look to you?

Comment: @ancide: when i write something longer, the first letter goes to next line, on continuing it goes in the same line itself.

Comment: solved: removed : `div{word-break:break-word} ` from the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself (But still doesnt' understand why), must be a bug in chrome.

I tried removing the following line from the css:

```
div{
   word-break:break-word;
}
```

tada.. it works like charm. So that must be a bug in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to down the font size in its css or up the heigth of the box

In css of the text, add padding-bottom and put it for example to 3px... Try it!

Comment: @Shahal Tharique: but don't remove css, only change the font size of the text and put it less. For example, to 11px

Answer (score 0):

You could set an 'overflow':

```
overflow:scroll;
```

this will make it scroll...

But it's down to the text is too long... either make it wider or reduce text size.

Comment: scrolling is letting it go more down. i want an input box, like a normal one. i tried `overflow:hidden;` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class for input box like:
.input_box {height:23px;width:600px;font-size:14px;}
 and use it. Try altering the width and height if text is wrapping.

Comment: it's solved, the problem was with the `div{word-break:break-word}` in css. any idea how the div affects input.

Comment: @Shahal Tharique -- welcome to SO! Now that you have your answer, you should go ahead and submit it as an answer for the question, then click the big checkmark to accept it. That will mark the question as solved and point everyone to the correct solution in the future.